# Sonatype Nexus - can not login anymore with admin user

Tags: nexus, sonatype

I have a Sonatype Nexus installed and I have the default user admin / admin123.
Now I changed the Authenticating Realm to LDAP and removed `XML Authenticating Realm` and `XML Authorizing Realm`. LDAP is not working and my admin account is also not working. I think it is because I disabled the XML Realm. How can I enable this? I have full access to the filesystem. The password can not be the problem, I did not change it.

So I can not login anymore. What can I do?

Best Regards, Tim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the nexus.xml to insert the Xml Realm back in and restart Nexus.

Comment: Nowadays its `security-configuration.xml` -- same idea though

Comment: where is this in 3.3.0-01?